# How do you render html text formatted using rich:editor in seam pdf

Tags: pdf, richfaces, seam, itext

How do you render a text formatted via rich:editor using seam pdf p:paragraph tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{yourBean.yourString}" />
```